# What is 死んだってなるもんか

Tags: grammar, translation

From a manga. A guy wants a girl to become his property. She retorts:

> あんたみたいな奴のものになんか (new bubble) 死んだってなるもんか！！

I get that she doesn't want to.

I think the translation might be something like "The property of someone like you?! I'd rather die!"

I'm puzzled by the construction of 死んだってなるもんか. I know that もんか is like a rhetoric question. Is Vだって the "even if" たって? How does that sentence work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 死んだって just means "even if I (must) die", which is inserted between ものに and なる. (～に)なる here is a plain verb, "to become". The sentence makes perfect sense without this clause:

> あんたみたいな奴のものになんか**なる**もんか!!
>   I won't **become** (such a thing as) the property of someone like you!

Comment: So 死んだって is an emphasis like "over my dead body" / "you will have to kill me if you want me to be your property"?

Comment: @Prune Yes exactly, it's a common way of strongly refusing something, e.g., "死んだって嫌だ!"

Answer (score 0):

あんたみたいな奴のものになんか (new bubble) 死んだってなるもんか！！

It's wordier and in reverse order (for more emphasis) in the original Japanese but it boils down to, "I'd rather be dead than be someone like YOU!!"

Comment: でも・・　`be someone like YOU` だと「あんたみたいな奴になんか...」ですよね・・・ 　 質問文は「あんたみたいな奴**のもの**になんか...」ですよね・・